# C# Click a link if keyword matches in html

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make something that finds an item using name and colour when the button is pressed.
I want to have 2 text boxes with the colour and name of product.
In the example the name is "Flight Suit" and colour is "Woodland Camo".
The website may have more than 1 product with the same name and colour.

I also want the item to be found if the name is not exact. So if name is "Flight Suit" it should fine name when text box contains "flight"

```html
<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<a href="/shop/pants/hfr1oni4u/pty423v8i" style="height:150px;">
<img alt="54m1hrdynn4" height="150" src="//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/120999/vi/54M1hRDYnN4.jpg" width="150">
</a>
<h1>
<a href="/shop/pants/hfr1oni4u/pty423v8i" class="name-link">Flight Suit</a>
</h1>
<p>
<a href="/shop/pants/hfr1oni4u/pty423v8i" class="name-link">Woodland Camo</a>
</p>
</div>
</article>
```

I tried this already:

```
HtmlElementCollection links =  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.InnerText.Contains(Keyword.Text))
        link.InvokeMember("Click");


}
```

This same code is used for colour and item name. The problem with this is that it crashes if the category has more than 1 item with the same name and colour. It also only doesn't check them properly at the same time because they are using the same code except for different text box.

Comment: Why did you tag c# in the question?

Comment: I'm making a software in C# that finds the product in web browser.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be a c# question. What c# code have you tried to achieve the functionality you are describing. Could you please share that?

Comment: I just edited my post to show what I done.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest based on the code you have now, I would add a break; statement to stop your for loop and change your condition to check for the two values:

```
HtmlElementCollection links =  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    var linkText = link.InnerText;
    if (linkText.Contains(Keyword.Text) ||
        linkText.Contains(ColorTextbox.Text))
    {
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
        break;
    }
}
```

You didn't provide how your color textbox was named so I invented that for you. The reason your code crashed is caused by the fact that once you *clicked* the link in the webbrowser component, the HtmlElements in the collection are no longer valid, because the page is being reloaded.